# db:auto:migrate in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I have just updated my app from Rails 2.3.5 to Rails 3. One of the plugins I liked most was Auto Migrations by Dizzy: http://www.dizzy.co.uk/ruby_on_rails/contents/auto-migrations

This allowed me to make changes in the database simply by altering the schema then running db:auto:migrate.

This plugin does not seem to be working in Rails 3. Do you guys know either how to get it working or do you know of other migration tools I can use to automatically migrate my existing (long) schema into my new empty database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following updated plugin:
[Auto Migrations](https://github.com/Suave/auto_migrations)

Answer (score 1):

You can use hobo fields, a part of the hobo project which doesn't require the whole hobo suite

http://cookbook.hobocentral.net/manual/hobo_fields

You'll want version 1.3 for Rails 3